# The output crop width and height in Android intent crop is not as set

Tags: android, android-image

I use intent crop to crop an image file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setType("image/*");
```

The new width is the original width.
The new height is the half of the new (also original) width, a little smaller than the original width.

```
Uri imageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
intent.setData(imageCaptureUri);
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("outputX", mCameraPreview.mCameraSize.width);  // mCameraPreview.mCameraSize.width is the picture size I set for camera parameters; so it is also the photo's width.
intent.putExtra("outputY", mCameraPreview.mCameraSize.width/2);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
```

Note:  mCameraPreview.mCameraSize.width is the picture size I set for camera parameters; so it is also the photo's width. By debugging, I have confirmed it equals the photo's width.
But on the UI of the crop intent, the cropping rectangular is not as extending as the original width. The cropping rectangular width is around 3/5 of the original width.

Since the com.android.camera.action.CROP is not documented, I do not know what should be a correct way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should log the value of `mCameraPreview.mCameraSize.width`. Camera's Preview sizes have different default value on different devices.

I think use the `pictureFile`'s size is a simple way to solve it.

```
photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageCaptureUri.getPath());
/* then get width and height */
photo_width = photo.getWidth();
photo_height = photo.getHeight();
intent.putExtra("outputX", photo_width);
intent.putExtra("outputY", photo_width/2);
```

--EDIT--

You want to adjust the initial size of cropping rect?
That seems impossible, the cropping rect is always set to the center of target image, with a default size. The size only changes by dragging on the screen.

Parameter `outputX` and `outputY` here only affect the **output size** of cropped image.

https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage
Here is the source code. Just DIY!

Comment: I used debugging, to confirm that the width the photo's width, since it is the picturesize set for the camera.

Comment: Sorry. I should've put it more clear: that size is the picturesize I set for the camera. I used debugging, to confirm that the width the photo's width, since it is the picturesize set for the camera.

Comment: So you mean,  the initial size of cropping rect is different from outputX and outputY? The design would be very misleading.

Comment: Yes. They are different, and the initial size is somehow unchangeable.  Edit the source code may be the only way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. After experiments, I find that outputX and output Y seem not to work at all. The cropped image is the image within the cropping rect, no matter what you set to outputX and outputY. From the source code, it uses Bitmap's method. I first thought in order to avoid out of memory, it would use native code. it limits the pixle number is less than 5M. Since this intent accounts for one application, so the available memory would be enough for it. If I create my own cropping activity embedded in my application, the memory would be a big issue.